# How to use ! non-confusingly?

Tags: javascript, jshint

My JavaScript code features an `if` statement with the following (IMHO very simple) condition:

```
if (a !== !!b) {
}
```

Now, [JSHint](https://jshint.com/) complains as follows, while marking the first exclamation mark in front of `b`:

> JSHint: Confusing use of '!'. (W018)

**How do I change this line to be non-confusing (as defined by JSHint) without changing its semantics, and without splitting it up into several instructions?**

---

To be clear: `a` is a boolean, while `b` may or may not be a boolean.

Comment: `a === !b` would be correct, if `a` is a boolean.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: JSHint finds the `!` in front of `b` confusing, as well.

Comment: Wrap `!!b` in parens.

Comment: @Teemu: No difference.

Comment: To make this sure: `a` is a boolean, and `b` is not a boolean, and you need to compare these two as booleans?

Comment: @Teemu: Exactly. (`b` is *probably* a boolean, but might also be `undefined` or `null` sometimes.)

Comment: Then the linter is the only-one confused here ...

Comment: Both variables are boolean?

Comment: @EsdrasXavier: No, `b` may or may not be boolean.

Comment: Case not be boolean what could they be? Null or undefined? Or numbers?

Comment: @EsdrasXavier: Probably `null` or `undefined`, though come to think of it, there might also be an object there.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the lint error, make an explicit conversion: `Boolean(b)`.

Comment: Not correct, but just FYI you can disable the warning by putting `/*jshint -W018 */` before the expression and `/*jshint +W018 */` after it

Comment: please add the types and the values to the question.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: Sure, though those two lines on their own are "confusing" (to me, as a reader), already, in that a disabled warning is always a bit of a red flag and calls my attention. Thanks for pointing it out, though.

Comment: What you could try is `if (a ^ Boolean(b)) { /* your stuff */ } `

Comment: @EsdrasXavier yes, that's not confusing at all :P

Comment: Sorry about that haha... The idea was use the **XOR** operator to reduce the `a !== !!b` to just `a ^ b`. Is the same far as I know XD

Comment: @EsdrasXavier: Unfortunately, it is not: `true ^ Boolean(4)` yields `0`, but `true ^ 4` yields `5`. Bitwise xor, *iff* `b` happens to be a number after all, or a string with a number in it :) And `true ^ {a: 1}` yields `1`, whereas `true ^ Boolean({a: 1})` yields `0`.

Comment: Yep in this case will be wrong because the **b** was not a boolean, but what I had in my mind was just _true_ and _false_ not numbers bigger than that or strings. But thanks for your reply, I should have take a look at the big picture :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it be that the ubiquitous JS idiom, `!!` for boolean conversion, is confusing to JSHint? If so: 1) maybe it can be turned off in the config, 2) you can try the more verbose `if (a !== Boolean(b))`.

Comment: Going with the verbose option suggested here, thank you.